# Cordova directory error when Android running Meteor App on Mac OS

Tags: javascript, android, macos, cordova, meteor

I'm trying meteor at this times. I wrote sample app and working correctly but when I trying run my app in android mode, I got an error on terminal screen.

Terminal screenshot below

[image: My terminal output]

What I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try running `meteor list-platforms` to check the installed platform for your project. if android isn't install, then run `meteor add-platform android`

Comment: I installed android and ios platforms with `meteor install-sdk android`, `meteor install-sdk ios` commands and then i add platforms to projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `meteor add-platform android` and then you can use `meteor run android`.

Comment: sorry but i already tried this. this not solution of my problem.

Comment: Ok, try this. Create a new project from scratch and add the android platform to it. See if you can get the basic default meteor app to run on the emulator before doing anything else.